# Make closure compliant with typedef

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, swift3

I'm converting some ObjC code to Swift 3 and one class in a used ObjC framework requires a completion block that complies to a typedef:

Objective-C:

```
workflow = [[Workflow alloc] initWithSettings:settings completion:^(AuthenticationAccount *account, NSError *error)
{
    print("Do something ...")
}];

// The header for initWithSettings looks like this:

- (instancetype)initWithSettings:(Settings *)settings completion:(nullable authentication_account_completion_block_t)completion AUTH_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;

// authentication_account_completion_block_t typedef:

typedef void (^authentication_account_completion_block_t)(AuthenticationAccount * __nullable account, NSError * __nullable error);
#define AUTH_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER NS_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER AUTH_NO_DISCARD
```

How can I convert this correctly to Swift so that the completion block still complies to the `authentication_account_completion_block_t` typedef?
If I simply optional-cast the closure to `authentication_account_completion_block_t` the block isn't executed ever:

Swift:

```
let workflow = Workflow(settings: settings!, completion:
{
    (account:AuthenticationAccount, error:Error?) in
        // Never executed!
        print("Do something ...")
} as? authentication_account_completion_block_t)

workflow.start()
```

Comment: how about if you typedef `authentication_account_completion_block_t` as optional?

Comment: I cannot touch that since it's a company internal framework.

Comment: interesting scenario .... i think only option is to use it as it is and trying catching exception if it's null.

Comment: Hmm that would be OK but the closure is always `nil` and provides the `AuthenticationAccount` which I need and can't get in any other way.

Comment: I worked around the issue. Since I'm additionally using a framework that is maintained by my team I added a wrapper method to that framework which uses the ObjC method (as above) and then dispatches NSNotifications with the account/error objects.

Comment: The `account` argument just needs to be of type `AuthenticationAccount?` (and then remove the cast `as? authentication_account_completion_block_t`). But you should remove the explicit type annotations from closure arguments anyway, and instead let the compiler infer them.

Comment: A typedef isn't a compliance thing. A typedef is just another name for the type. Are you sure you even need to cast here? What error do you get if you leave away the "as" cast?